# PHP search in a variable text

Tags: php

I have this variable:

```
$var = "261202 31012TF 4444 RUFOK 15/18 Q5242 PARLO";
```

and I would like to save that part of of the variable that starts with Q (Q5242)

How can I search in this $var and save it? I cant use `substr` cause `$var`'s value is always changing and it is always in another "place" in the variable.

**For example:**

**First case:**

```
$var = "261202 31012TF 4444 RUFOK 15/18 Q5242 PARLO";
```

**Second case:**

```
$var = "261202 31012TF Q5242 4444 RUFOK 15/18 PARLO";
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So it's always a 'Q' followed by 4 digits? Smells like a regex job... like `/Q\d{4}/`

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: It looks like auto generated text. Can there be more than one Q in the text? Substr and strpos is one way that can do it if you don't like regex

Comment: Regex or `explode()` then foreach and check the first letter if `Q` should do the job

Comment: No, theres no more Q and yes always followed by 4 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substr and strpos solution.
Comments in code.

```
$var = ["261202 31012TF 4444 RUFOK 15/18 Q5242 PARLO",
        "261202 31012TF Q5242 4444 RUFOK 15/18 PARLO"]; 

foreach($var as $v){
    $pos = strpos($v, "Q"); // find Q
    // Echo substring from Q to next space
    echo substr($v, $pos, strpos($v," ",$pos)-$pos) . "\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/5f740

Answer (score 2):

```
$pattern = '/\bQ[^\s]+/'
```

Would match any "word" starting with Q up until it reaches a whitespace.

```
$pattern = '/\bQ\d{4}/'
```

Would be more strict, matching a word starting with Q and followed by 4 digits.

```
preg_match($pattern, $var, $matches);
```

Could be used to pull the matches from the strings.